# Line on the left hand side of multirow?

Tags: matrices, border

I am currently working with this code:

```
    \begin{tabular}{ll|l|l|}
        \cline{3-4}
                                 &                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Predictions} \\ \cline{3-4}
                                 &                            & High      & Low \\ \cline{1-4}
        \multirow{2}{*}{Guesses} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{High} &   14      & 0   \\ \cline{2-4}
                                 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Low}  &   3       & 50  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

And it produces this result:

[image]

I would either like to add a line to the left end of ''Guesses'' or remove the lines above and underneath ''Guesses'', as well as the lines above, and to the sides of, ''Predictions''. Is there a way to do this?

If anyone has a superb way of constructing simple confusion matrices, I can take that advice as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to salim bou I was able to achieve what I wanted. The code below strips ''Predictions'' and ''Guesses'' of all lines.

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{}                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Predictions} \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                           & High & Low                      \\ \cline{2-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Actual Quality}} & High &  14 &  0                 \\ \cline{2-4}
                                                    & Low  &   3 & 50                 \\ \cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
```

Whilst this code encapsulates everything:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                           & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Predictions} \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                           & High & Low                       \\ \cline{1-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{1.5cm}{Actual Quality}} & High &  14 &  0                  \\ \cline{2-4}
                                                    & Low  &   3 & 50                  \\ \cline{1-4}
\end{tabular}
```

Cheers

Comment: This is not answer to your question but how to make multi-line multi-row cells. This can be obtained on simpler way as you doing ...

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|l|}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Predictions} \\ \cline{3-4}
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}           & High & Low \\ \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Guesses} & High &  14  & 0   \\ \cline{2-4}
                           & Low  &  3   & 50  \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code did not do exactly what I wanted, but I was able to reach my solution above by using the tips you gave (adding multicolums to oppress the long lines for the multirow).

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your picture of desired table in question and your own answer I combine in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
                                                    \cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}                & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Predictions} 
                                                    \\ \cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}               & High  & Low   \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{1.5cm}{Actual 
                    Quality} & High &  14   & 0     \\ \cline{2-4}
                             & Low  &  3   & 50     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]